# Polymer template.render() is unreliable

Tags: javascript, polymer

I use the following code, in simplified form.
I have a template that shows a list of stores, coming from the _stores array. Depending on some other properties that are set in the app, the _sort and _filter function do their respective work well and show the list I want to see.

When I recalculate distances for each store (running _stores trough calculateDistance) I want to re-render the storelist by calling _search(), which calls the Polymer .render() function.

**This call is not reliable: sometimes it renders, sometimes not.** It happens on desktop and mobile, safari and android, so it seems like it is a Polymer issue. I cannot find what is causing this. Any idea?

```
 <template id="storeList" is="dom-repeat" items="{{_stores}}" sort="_sort" filter="_filter">
      <div class="search_result">
        <div class="picture">

          <div class="logo" hidden$="{{!item.logo.length}}">
            <div class="centered">
              <img src$="{{item.logo}}" alt="logo" />
            </div>
          </div>....
</template>


<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'user-store-search-page',

  properties: {
    ...
    _stores: Array
    ...
    },
    _calculateDistance: function () {
       this._stores.forEach(s) {
           //do stuff per store

       }
    },
    _filter: function (store) {
         //do filtering stuff
    },
    _sort: function (a, b) {
         //sort stuff
    },
    _search: function () {
        this.$.storeList.render();
    }
```

Comment: do you need to actually render this list? any change on your array should be visible

Comment: I thought so too. 
I see that I do use native JavaScript array mutations. That's why I called render.

What is strange, is that is sometimes DOES render!

I have found a workaround by creating an empty object:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use compute property advantage for rerender your list on any action performed on _stores Array :)

```
 <template id="storeList" is="dom-repeat" items="[[_displayStores]]" sort="_sort" filter="_filter">
  <div class="search_result">
    <div class="picture">

      <div class="logo" hidden$="{{!item.logo.length}}">
        <div class="centered">
          <img src$="{{item.logo}}" alt="logo" />
        </div>
      </div>....
</template>


<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'user-store-search-page',

  properties: {
    ...
    _stores: Array,
    _displayStores: {
      type: Array,
      computed: '_computeStoresToDisplay(_stores.*)'
    }
    ...
    },
    _computeStoresToDisplay: function(stores) {
      return stores.value;
    },
    _calculateDistance: function () {
       this._stores.forEach(s) {
           //do stuff per store

       }
    },
    _filter: function (store) {
         //do filtering stuff
    },
    _sort: function (a, b) {
         //sort stuff
    },
    _search: function () {
        this.$.storeList.render();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works quite well, but seems that pushing the splices into the template fills up my console (eventually it renders:)

polymer-micro.html:277 [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: expected array for `items`, found 
Object {keySplices: Array(1), indexSplices: Array(1)}

Comment: och sorry, then it should not be stores.value maybe :)) checkout this object and you will see what to use

Comment: Actually, after some more research I found out that the distance values are not updating in the list, if the list itself doesn't change: even with your fix.

The list is sorted on distance, but when the distances change but the sorting stays equal, Polymer is not showing the new distance. Only if I force a different sorting on other tags / filtering.